# Problem with Absolute path and Relative path in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am facing problem with Absolute path and Relative path in batch file...I have program as

```
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set LOCATION=D:\TESTING\a\b\try

set OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt
set SEARCHTEXT=hello
set REPLACETEXT=world


FOR /r %LOCATION% %%x IN (\*.txt,\*.java) (
DO echo %%x
SET INTEXTFILE=%%x
)


for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (

SET string=%%A

SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)

del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

It should read all txt and java files from "D:\TESTING\a\b\try" dir and change the text 'hello' to 'world' in them

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Have you tried this script yet? If so, what results do you get? I think your `INTEXTFILE` variable here remembers only the last piece found by the first loop. Is that intended to be so?

Comment: I GOT THE ANSWER ......



@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set LOCATION=D:\TESTING\a\b\try\

set OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt
set SEARCHTEXT=hello
set REPLACETEXT=world


FOR /r %LOCATION% %%x IN (\*.txt) do (

for /f "tokens=1,\* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %%x"') do (

SET string=%%A

SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!



echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)

del %%x
copy %OUTTEXTFILE% %%x
del %OUTTEXTFILE%
echo location  %%x
)
THANK U ALL FOR UR HELP

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set LOCATION=D:\TESTING\a\b\try\

set OUTTEXTFILE=temp.txt

set SEARCHTEXT=world

set REPLACETEXT=hello


FOR /r %LOCATION% %%x IN (*.txt,*.java) do (

FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %%x"') do (

SET string=%%A

SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)

del %%x

copy %OUTTEXTFILE% %%x

del %OUTTEXTFILE%

echo location  %%x

)
```